# object gets hit but the score is not updating

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a simple game (will show just the trouble part) Everything is working great except the `health` score. I  put a print statement to check if one object gets hit by another. So, the `if statement` is `True` because I see the print statement, but my `health` score is not updating. Am I missing something here? Thank you for your help!

```
sqrls = pygame.image.load("crazySquirrel1.gif")
sqrlsrect = sqrls.get_rect()
sqrls_startx = 200
sqrls_starty = 530
sqrlsrect.center = (sqrls_startx, sqrls_starty)

girl = pygame.image.load('girl1.gif')
girlrect = girl.get_rect()
x = 850
y = 278
girlrect.center = (x, y)
screen.blit(girl,(x, y))    

## adding health score
health = 3
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 20)
text = font.render("Health: " + str(health),1, RED)
## main game loop **********************************
x_change = 0
endGame = False

while not endGame:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0               
    x += x_change

    sqrlsrect = sqrlsrect.move(sqrls_speed) # moving squirrel 1
    if sqrlsrect.left < 0 or sqrlsrect.right > w:
        sqrls_speed[0] = -sqrls_speed[0]
    if sqrlsrect.top < 0 or sqrlsrect.bottom > h:
        sqrls_speed[1] = -sqrls_speed[1]

    if sqrlsrect.center == girlrect.center:
       print ('Ouch s!')  
       health -= 1

    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(sqrls, sqrlsrect)
    screen.blit(girl, (x, y))
    screen.blit(text, (w*0.88, h*0.03))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are modifying `health`, you aren't modifying the actual text which is being displayed. Instead, try using the following:

```
if sqrlsrect.center == girlrect.center:
       print ('Ouch s!')  
       health -= 1
       text = font.render("Health: " + str(health),1, RED)
```

Comment: Thank you SO very much! It worked! You are brilliant!